# An asymptotic characterization for a series

Tags: enumerative-combinatorics

I have been working on characterizing the asymptotic behavior for large $n$ for the following sum:

$$\Gamma(1+t)\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\binom{n}{k} (-1)^{k-1}}{k^t}$$

where $t(>0)$ is a given constant. The case for $t=1$ can be somewhat found here:

http://www.math.wvu.edu/~gould/Vol.4.PDF

in equation $8.25$. Using this equation, for large $n$, the sum behaves as $\log(n)$. I am trying to understand if similar behavior can be obtained for a general $t>0$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematica does the job for concrete values of $t\in \mathbb{N}$:

```
Series[Gamma[1 + 2]*Sum[Binomial[n, k]*(-1)^(k - 1)/k^2, {k, 1, n}], {n, Infinity, 2}]
```

> $$\left(\log ^2(n)+2 \gamma  \log (n)+\gamma ^2+\frac{\pi ^2}{6}\right)+\frac{\log (n)+\gamma -1}{n}+\frac{-2 \log (n)-2 \gamma +9}{12 n^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^3\right)  $$

```
Series[Gamma[1 + 3]*Sum[Binomial[n, k]*(-1)^(k - 1)/k^3, {k, 1, n}], {n, Infinity, 2}]
```

> $$\left(\log ^3(n)+3 \gamma  \log ^2(n)+3 \gamma ^2 \log (n)+\frac{1}{2} \pi ^2 \log (n)+2 \zeta (3)+\gamma ^3+\frac{\gamma  \pi ^2}{2}\right)+\frac{6 \log ^2(n)+12 \gamma  \log (n)-12 \log (n)+6 \gamma ^2+\pi ^2-12 \gamma }{4 n}+\frac{-6 \log ^2(n)-12 \gamma  \log (n)+54 \log (n)-6 \gamma ^2-\pi ^2+54 \gamma -60}{24 n^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^3\right) $$

The output for $t=4$ is too long to be cited here. Mathematica fails with $t= \frac 5 2$.

Comment: Thanks! From the results, it seems that the sum is $\Theta(\log^t(n))$! It would be great if we can find some way to prove that analytically.

Comment: @Saurav: If you are a Mathematica user, you may submit a request about the source of the above formulas to WolframTechnicalSupport. Up to my experience, they give a constructive answer in each case.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that, and will update here if they provide some help.

Comment: The sum can be evaluated by Mathematica explicitly in terms of products of polygammas (for integer t).  The expression is not super-enlightening, but is more so than the power series.

Comment: @IgorRivin Thanks for the info! I will keep that in mind.